# How to limit image height in tumblr?

Tags: html, css

I am using a hi res Tumblr theme... 
Horizontal images fill the screen as expected. Square images are too tall to fit on the screen.
How can I create a limit or container so that posted images will only be allowed to reach the full 1280 px width if the vertical expanse will remain on screen?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

use this. this simple css code will limit all images to 1280px.
-your question dosn't clear-

img{width:1280px;}